# Javascript port var test = { a: Infinity }

Tags: javascript, swift, porting

I'm porting some Javascript code to Swift, I was hoping for some help with some of the shorthand code. I am familiar with most code but I find the shorthand is really difficult to read.

In one function a variable is defined as

```
var test = { a: Infinity };
```

In another function the variable is returned as part of what looks like a comparison in shorthand:

```
return {a: b}
```

Could someone explain this code?

Here is the code I am porting (raycasting):

```
Map.prototype.cast = function(point, angle, range) {
    var self = this;
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var noWall = { length2: Infinity };

    return ray({ x: point.x, y: point.y, height: 0, distance: 0 });

    function ray(origin) {
        var stepX = step(sin, cos, origin.x, origin.y);
        var stepY = step(cos, sin, origin.y, origin.x, true);
        var nextStep = stepX.length2 < stepY.length2 ? inspect(stepX, 1, 0, origin.distance, stepX.y) : inspect(stepY, 0, 1, origin.distance, stepY.x);

        if (nextStep.distance > range) return [origin];
    return [origin].concat(ray(nextStep));
    }


    function step(rise, run, x, y, inverted) {
        if (run === 0) return noWall;
        var dx = run > 0 ? Math.floor(x + 1) - x : Math.ceil(x - 1) - x;
        var dy = dx * (rise / run);
        return { x: inverted ? y + dy : x + dx, y: inverted ? x + dx : y + dy, length2: dx * dx + dy * dy };
}
```

The part I am confused with is:

```
var noWall = { length2: Infinity };
and
length2: dx * dx + dy * dy
```

what do these do?

Thanks

Greg

Comment: So you're asking to convert this JavaScript code to Swift?

Comment: `return test: b` should be a syntax error. The `test:` would be closest to a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), which can't be used within an expression. That is, unless a preprocessor is being used -- e.g. [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/).

Comment: `var test = { a: Infinity }` is pretty darn straight forward and hardly "shorthand"...!?

Answer (score 1):

This code is a syntax error in JavaScript:

```
return test: b
```

I'm guessing your code is not intended to be run through a standard JavaScript compiler and the "test" part probably has something to do with a Unit Testing system of some kind.

Double check with someone more familiar with the code if you can, but otherwise just use this as your Swift code:

```
return b
```